# Is there a way to protect only some cells from re-formatting?

Tags: formatting, lock, cell-format

I have a .xlsm file that users input information to in unprotected cells.  Users need to be able to add as many rows as necessary and to reformat the cells the added.  However, I do not want them to mess with the formatting of the protected cells.  Can anyone tell me a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean you want to allow them to enter data into the protected cells but do not want them to format the protected cells, do the following (these instructions are for Excel 2019 and the method may be slightly different for earlier versions):

1. Select all required protected cells
2. Go to 'Format > Format Cells'
3. Click on the 'Protection' tab
4. Untick 'locked'
5. Click on 'OK' to exit the dialog box
6. Now go to 'Format > Protect Sheet'
7. Scroll down the list and tick 'Edit objects'
8. Make sure the 'Format cells' option is unticked if it isn't already
9. Optionally browse the list and tick or untick anything else you're interested in
10. Click 'OK' to exit.

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However, no, there are protected cells that make up the top part of a form.  Below that there is a section where the user can add as many rows as they would like to input information.  I would like them to be able to format the sells in those rows (except for the width) but not mess with the format of the protected cells above.  I have not figured out a way to do this.